# Insert permission for users inside sharedDrive

Tags: c#, google-drive-api

I want to add members inside specific shared drive (Team drive).
i have tried with inserting permission request as below:

```
 var listPermisssion = new List<TeamDrivePermissionDetailsData>() { };
                TeamDrivePermissionDetailsData permission = new TeamDrivePermissionDetailsData()
                {
                    Role = role,
                    TeamDrivePermissionType ="member" ,

                };

                listPermisssion.Add(permission);

                Permission tdrivePermission = new Permission();
                tdrivePermission.EmailAddress = who;
                tdrivePermission.TeamDrivePermissionDetails = listPermisssion;
                var requestPermission = service.Permissions.Create(tdrivePermission, sharedDriveId);
                requestPermission.Execute();
```

i got this error :
 Error:'Google.Apis.Requests.RequestError

> The permission role field is required. [400]

thnks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

The method `Permissions:create` requires the specification of `role` and `type` as described in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/permissions/create?)

- `member` is not a valid option for `type` - it should be one of the following options:

  - user
  - group
  - domain
  - anyone
- `role` expects one of the following options:

  - owner
  - organizer
  - fileOrganizer
  - writer
  - commenter
  - reader